# Duplicar uma associação em ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou com uma dúvida.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Envio a tabela que já fiz, mas tenho um problema, no caso do `"Isolate's name" "catx"` tenho dois `"gene's name" associado, "catxx" e o "catxxx"`, mas eu estou a colocar os dois na mesma linha e gostava de duplicar a linha, uma para o "catxx" e outra para o "catxxx". Como faço, não estou a conseguir encontrar a solução. O código que tenho é:

```
  <tbody>
    <% if @resists.any? == true%>
    <% @resists.each do |resist| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= resist.isolated.organism.tax_org if resist.isolated%>
        <td><%= resist.isolated.organism.name if resist.isolated%>
        <td><%= resist.isolated.name if resist.isolated%>
        <td><%= resist.isolated.disease if resist.isolated%>
        <td><%= resist.drug.name%>
        <td><%= resist.drug.reference%>
        <td><%= resist.drug.atc%>
        <td><%if resist.isolated %>
        <% @genes.each do |gene| %>
          <%if resist.isolated.id == gene.isolated_id%>
            <%= gene.name%>
          <%end%>
       <%end%>
       <%end%>
     </td>
```

@genes, vai buscar os genes todos.

estou a fazer

```
<% @genes.each do |gene| %>
          <%if resist.isolated.id == gene.isolated_id%>
            <%= gene.name%>
          <%end%>
       <%end%>
```

porque um isolado pode ter vários genes, e como tal, se fizer resist.isolated.gene.name vai-me dar erro porque tem mais que um. Mas como estou a fazer coloca-me na mesma linha os genes todos daquele isolado e eu queria colocar cada gene numa linha diferente, duplicando o isolado, claro.
Por exemplo:

```
123 xpto catx cenas12 navnav 2111 catxx
123 xpto catx cenas12 navnav 2111 catxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

assumindo que no seu model Resist.rb você tem:

```
has_many :genes
```

e no seu Gene.rb

```
belongs_to :resist
```

basta por na view:

```
    <% resist.genes.each do |gene| %>
      <%= gene.name%>
    <%end%>
   </td>
```